# Can't publish options with RabbitMQ message?

Tags: node.js, queue, rabbitmq

I'm using [ampq.node](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/) for my RabbitMQ access in my Node code. I'm trying to use either the `publish` or `sendToQueue` methods to include some metadata with my published message (namely timestamp and content type), using the `options` parameter.

But whatever I'm passing to `options` is completely ignored. I think I'm missing some formatting, or a field name, but I cannot find any reliable documentation (beyond the one provided [here](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/doc/channel_api.html) which does not seem to do the job).

Below is my `publish` function code:

```
  var publish = function(queueName, message) {
    let content;
    let options = {
      persistent: true,
      noAck: false,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      contentEncoding: 'utf-8'
    };
    if(typeof message === 'object') {
      content = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(message));
      options.contentType = 'application/json';
    }
    else if(typeof message === 'string') {
      content = new Buffer(message);
      options.contentType = 'text/plain';
    }
    else {  //message is already a buffer?
      content = message;
    }
    return Channel.sendToQueue(queueName, content, options); //Channel defined and opened elsewhere
  };
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**
Turns out if you choose to use a `ConfirmChannel`, you **must** provide the callback function as the last parameter, or else, the options object is ignored. So once I changed the code to the following, I started seeing the options correctly:

`Channel.sendToQueue(queueName, content, options, (err, result) => {...});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, I can't seem to get your example publish to work... though I don't see anything particularly wrong with it. I'm not sure why I wasn't able to get your example code working.

But I was able to modify a version of my own amqplib intro code, and got it working with your options just fine.

Here is the complete code for my example:

```
// test.js file

var amqplib = require("amqplib");

var server = "amqp://test:password@localhost/test-app";

var connection, channel;

function reportError(err){
  console.log("Error happened!! OH NOES!!!!");
  console.log(err.stack);
  process.exit(1);
}

function createChannel(conn){
  console.log("creating channel");
  connection = conn;
  return connection.createChannel();
}

function sendMessage(ch){
  channel = ch;

  console.log("sending message");
  var msg = process.argv[2];
  var message = new Buffer(msg);

  var options = {
    persistent: true,
    noAck: false,
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    contentEncoding: "utf-8",
    contentType: "text/plain"
  };

  channel.sendToQueue("test.q", message, options);
  return channel.close();
}

console.log("connecting");
amqplib.connect(server)
  .then(createChannel)
  .then(sendMessage)
  .then(process.exit, reportError);
```

to run this, open a command line and do:

`node test.js "example text message"`

After running that, you'll see the message show up in your "test.q" queue (assuming you have that queue created) in your "test-app" vhost.

Here's a screenshot of the resulting message from the RMQ Management plugin:

[image: message from rmq server]

---

side notes:

I recommend not using `sendToQueue`. As I say in my [**RabbitMQ Patterns** email course / ebook](http://derickbailey.com/email-courses/rabbitmq-patterns-for-applications/):

> It took a while for me to realize this, but I now see the "send to queue" feature of RabbitMQ as an anti-pattern.
>
> Sure, it's built in to the library and protocol. And it's convenient, right? But that doesn't mean you should use it. It's one of those features that exists to make demos simple and to handle some specific scenarios. But generally speaking, "send to queue" is an anti-pattern.
>
> When you're a message producer, you only care about sending the message to the right exchange with the right routing key. When you're a message consumer, you care about the message destination - the queue to which you are subscribed. A message may be sent to the same exchange, with the same routing key, every day, thousands of times per day. But, that doesn't mean it will arrive in the same queue every time.
>
> As message consumers come online and go offline, they can create new queues and bindings and remove old queues and bindings. This perspective of message producers and consumers informs the nature of queues: postal boxes that can change when they need to.

I also recommend not using amqplib directly. It's a great library, but it lacks a lot of usability. Instead, look for a good library on top of amqplib.

I prefer [wascally, by LeanKit](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/wascally). It's a much easier abstraction on top of amqplib and provides a lot of great features and functionality.

Lastly, if you're struggling with other details in getting RMQ up and running with Node.js, designing your app to work with it, etc., check out my [RabbitMQ For Devs](http://rabbitmq4devs.com) course - it goes from zero to hero, fast. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Derick. Could the fact that I'm using a Confirm Channel be an issue? (and yes, I removed the callback code from my sample - thought it'd make it look cleaner).

Comment: honestly have never used the ConfirmChannel plugin, so I don't know if that would cause something like this or not. I wouldn't think so... but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

this may help others, but the key name to use for content type is **contentType** in the javascript code. Using the web Gui for rabbitMQ, they use **content_type** as the key name. different key names to declare options, so make sure to use the right one in the right context.